# Firefox does not prevent sleep while watching video

Tags: firefox, suspend

I just installed Xubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and I'm very happy with this distro.

However, Firefox does not seem to prevent sleep when watching videos, which is really irritating.

Does anyone know how to fix this please?